# Optimize the CSV Upload function in Ruby On Rails

Tags: performance, ruby, ruby-on-rails, error-handling

The code is working fine however, I would like to fix code after unless and can I store thread ID in the database too? Is there a way to improve performance?

```
require 'csv'
    class CsvDb
      class << self
        def convert_save(model_name, csv_data, field_name=nil)
          target_model = model_name.classify.constantize
          csv_file = csv_data.read
          row_headers={}
          counter=0;
          #Thread.new do
                    CSV.parse(csv_file) do |row| 
                        if counter==0
                            temp=row
                            row_headers = Hash[temp.map.with_index.to_a]
                            counter +=1
                            next
                        end
                        unless row[row_headers["name"]].nil?
                            temp={}
                            business_type = row[row_headers["business_type_id"]]
                            business_type_id = business_type=='Online' ? 1: business_type=='Local' ? 2: 3
                            temp[:business_type_id]         = business_type_id
                            temp[:user_id]                          = row[row_headers["user_id"]]
                            temp[:name]                                 = row[row_headers["name"]]
                            temp[:country_id]                   = row[row_headers["country_id"]]
                            temp[:homepage]                         = row[row_headers["homepage"]] ||=""
                            temp[:telephone]                        = row[row_headers["telephone"]] ||=""
                            temp[:email]                                = row[row_headers["email"]] ||=""
                            temp[:address]                          = row[row_headers["address"]] ||=""
                            temp[:latitude]                         = row[row_headers["latitude"]] 
                            temp[:longitude]                        = row[row_headers["longitude"]]
                            temp[:facebook]                         = row[row_headers["facebook"]] ||=""
                            temp[:twitter]                          = row[row_headers["twitter"]] ||=""
                            temp[:google]                           = row[row_headers["google"]] ||=""
                            temp[:instagram]                        = row[row_headers["instagram"]] ||=""
                            temp[:pinterest]                        = row[row_headers["pinterest"]] ||=""
                            temp[:free_shipping]                = row[row_headers["free_shipping"]]
                            temp[:ship_details]                 = row[row_headers["ship_details"]] ||=""
                            temp[:category_ids]                 = [row[row_headers["category_ids"]]]
                            temp[:style_ids]                        = [row[row_headers["style_ids"]]]
                            temp[:shipping_country_ids] = [row[row_headers["shipping_country_ids"]]]
                            business = target_model.new(temp)
                            business.save
                        end
                    end
                    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close
          end
        #end
      end   
    end
```

Comment: `I would like to fix code after unless and can I store thread ID in the database too?` Could you re-phrase that? I have no idea what you're trying to convey.

Comment: What do you mean by `fix` after `unless`, are you talking about formatting ? You know fixing code is off-topic.

Comment: By "fix code" do you mean "improve"?

Comment: I am not asking about formatting, I am asking about using map filter that will make 14 line to two or three

Comment: Fix means to improve not formatting, Second concern is that if thread start a task how could I know that thread complete the task or not.

Comment: Currently object is stored one by one and take much time even for 200 records

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code is not tested, maybe some minor changes will be necessary: I'm not 100% sure it will work as is, don't hesitate to tell me if there is anything wrong with the code

### Refactoring the existing code

The first thing I did was to set the `headers` option to `true` it will enable the parsing of the first line of the CSV and instead of giving you an array for each row it will return an hashmap with keys extracted from the header. It replace the code you wrote to parse the header of the file.

Then I replace the imbricated ternary operations to use a `case when` expression for the `business_type_id` which is far more readable.

Next I made two small function to extract all the needed values, I use `reduce` to automatically fill a hashmap from an array of symboles.

At least I merge all the hashmap in the constructor of the `target_model` before saving.

```
CSV.parse(csv_file, {headers: true, header_converters: :symbol}) do |row|
  business_type_id =  case row[:business_type_id]
                        when 'Online' then 1
                        when 'Local' then 2
                        else 3
                      end

  target_model.new( {business_type_id: business_type_id} + extract_required_fields(row) + extract_optionals_fiels(row) )
              .save()

end

def extract_required_fields(row)
  [:user_id, :name, :country_id, :free_shipping, :category_ids, :style_ids, :shipping_country_ids]
    .reduce({}) do |carry, item|
      carry[item] = row[item]
  end
end

def extract_optionals_fiels(row)
  [:homepage, :telephone, :email, :address, :facebook, :twitter, :google, :instagram, :pinterest, :ship_details]
    .reduce({}) do |carry, item|
      carry[item] = row[item] ||= ''
  end
end
```

### Bulk update

But this code, even if it has a better separation of concern and less duplication will not really speed your import process because your performance bottleneck is in the insert operation performed for each item by the `save` method.

So the solution is to make a **bulk update** instead of saving each row separately: you'll group the insert !

To do so, you can use the https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import gem which will allow you to do something like this :

```
entities = []
CSV.parse(csv_file, {headers: true, header_converters: :symbol}) do |row|
  business_type_id =  case row[:business_type_id]
                        when 'Online' then 1
                        when 'Local' then 2
                        else 3
                      end

  entities << target_model.new( {business_type_id: business_type_id} + extract_required_fields(row) + extract_optionals_fiels(row) )
  target_model.import entities if entities.size == 100 
end

#don't forget to save the remaining entities:
target_model.import entities unless entities.size == 0
```

In this case we proceed the save operation each 100 row, which will make the import process way faster !

### Getting the Thread's ID

To collect the thread's Id, I suggest to use the `inspect` method of the `current_thread`, you'll get more information than only the thread's id but you'll be able to have all the needed informations about which thread processed the insert operation.

```
thread_identifier = Thread.current.inspect
```

Comment: Should I have to write code in model now or I can use same code as it is placed now.

Comment: You should be able to use the code as it is placed now

Comment: But there is issue with bulk update, I have to skip few columns which is not possible by gem.

Comment: You have to skip columns or row ? 
For the columns, just remove them from the constructor's hash, for the rows you can make the append (`<<`) conditional.

Comment: Need to remove columns because the column name is same as of nested model. That model is just for main user help who create csv: CSV has fields [:user_id, :shipping_countries, shipping_country_ids] here shipping_countries is useless. The first case cover this case but gem one not.

Comment: I don't understand the problem, the shipping_countries field is not set in the constructor's hash. If it is about linked entities you can try the  `recursive: true` option like `target_model.import(entities, recursive: true)`

Comment: Great Answer, (Y) and +50 you deserved. How can I share the CSV file here?

Comment: You can use "pastebin" to share the structure of the CSV

Answer (score 2):

No idea what "thread ID" means.

I'll just focus on the the translation of the CSV rows into an object.
There's just to much repetition in the `unless` body.  All those rows
should be mentioned once, then handled in a loop instead of hard coding
them like this.  E.g.

```ruby
unless row[row_headers["name"]].nil?
    temp={}
    business_type = row[row_headers["business_type_id"]]
    business_type_id = business_type == "Online" ? 1: business_type == "Local" ? 2 : 3
    temp[:business_type_id] = business_type_id
    for name in [:user_id, :name, :country_id, :latitude, :longitude, :free_shipping, :category_ids, :style_ids, :shipping_country_ids]
        temp[name] = row[row_headers[name.to_s]]
    end
    for name in [:homepage, :telephone, :email, :address, :facebook, :twitter, :google, :instagram, :pinterest, :ship_details]
        temp[name] = row[row_headers[name.to_s]] ||= ""
    end
    business = target_model.new(temp)
    business.save
end
```

That said, I'm sure there are better ways to do this in Ruby ...

Comment: thanks, since records are in millions and process take much time so I would like to do it using thread to improve performance. Here concern is that how can I store thread data and its status in the database because thread id can't be remain same.